# sort and rank in spark RDD in one file

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have an spark RDD as below

```
(maths,60)
(english,65)
(english,77)
(maths,23)
(maths,50)
```

I need to sort and rank the given RDD in one as below
(maths,23,1)
(maths,50,2)
(maths,50,3)
(english,65,1)
(english,77,2)

i know this can be done easily using Data Frame, but i need Spark rdd code to get the solution, please suggest

Answer (score 1):

**Spark `RDD`** functions(so called transformations) like `groupByKey` `flatMap` and **Scala `List`** function like `sorted` should helps in achieving it.

```
val rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(
  Seq(("maths",60), 
      ("english",65), 
      ("english",77), 
      ("maths",23), 
      ("maths",50)))

val result = rdd.groupByKey().flatMap(group => {

  group._2.toList
  .sorted.toList // sort marks
  .zipWithIndex // add the position/rank
  .map {

    case(marks, index) => (group._1, marks, index + 1)
  }
})

result.collect

// Array((english,65,1), (english,77,2), (maths,23,1), (maths,50,2), (maths,60,3))
```

[Databricks notebook](https://databricks-prod-cloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/public/4027ec902e239c93eaaa8714f173bcfc/5537430417240233/4345481965413946/3506802399907740/latest.html)

Comment: @devD: Glad that helps!! consider marking the answer as accepted so that community can know the question has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

Another rdd solution:

```
val df = Seq(("maths",60),("english",65),("english",77),("maths",23),("maths",50)).toDF("subject","marks")
val rdd1 = df.rdd
rdd1.groupBy( x=> x(0))
  .map( x=> 
      {
         val p = x._2.toList.map(a=>a(1)).map(_.toString.toInt).sortWith((a1,a2)=> a1 < a2 ).zipWithIndex.map(b=>(b._1,b._2+1))
        (x._1,p) 
      }
  )
  .flatMap( x => x._2.map((x._1,_)))
  .collect.foreach(println)
```

Results:

```
(english,(65,1))
(english,(77,2))
(maths,(23,1))
(maths,(50,2))
(maths,(60,3))
```